# Retrieving record from db returns object with id 0

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve an object from DB:

```
Selected_Group sg = 
    manager.get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(group_to_remove.getGroup_id(), trip_id);
```

This is the method in my DB Manager class:

```
public Selected_Group get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(int trip_id, int group_id)
{
    open_readable();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.Table_Names.TABLE_NAME_SELECTED_GROUPS, null, "trip_id="+trip_id+" AND group_id="+group_id, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int sg_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int sg_trip_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("trip_id");
    int sg_group_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("group_id");
    Selected_Group sg = new Selected_Group(sg_id, sg_trip_id, sg_group_id);
    cursor.close();
    close();
    return sg;
}
```

The parameters that are being passed, for example, are trip_id=18 and group_id=1. There's only one record matching these and it's _id=54. But for some reason I'm getting sg_id=0.

This is how my table was created in DB Helper class:

```
String create_table_selected_groups = "CREATE TABLE "+Constants.Table_Names.TABLE_NAME_SELECTED_GROUPS+" (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"+
            ", trip_id INTEGER, group_id INTEGER);";
db.execSQL(create_table_selected_groups);
```

I tried to get the sg_id like this:

```
 int sg_id = cursor.getInt(0);
```

but the app crashes with error message:

```
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.mycompany.myapp.tasks.Task_DB_Manager.get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(Task_DB_Manager.java:542)
08-01 14:31:17.416: E/AndroidRuntime(13385):    at com.mycompany.myapp.activities.Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.onClick(Activity_Add_Edit_Trip.java:263)
...
```

Why am I constantly getting 0 in sg_id? What's the problem here?

Comment: The query did not return any rows.

Comment: How is it possible? The row does exist in the db...

Comment: No it does not. Show the actual `trip_id` and `group_id` values, and the record you think should match.

Comment: You're correct, it didn't. I mixed with the parameters order, that's why I was getting 0 or was out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I constantly getting 0 in sg_id?

Because it's a column index.

To get the column value, use e.g. `getInt(index)` on the cursor.

Why you get

> CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

is because your cursor doesn't have any rows - the query didn't match anything. To avoid such exceptions, check that `moveTo...()` returns true before trying to access data in the cursor.

Comment: OK, I found what was causing the problem, this line: `manager.get_selected_group_by_group_id_and_trip_id(group_to_remove.getGroup_id(), trip_id)` I should've passed trip_id as first parameter, not the second. And then, of course, change `getColumnIndex()` back to `getInt()`. Now I'm having the ID of the Selected_Group. Thanks!